# Creating a self-destructing(encryption keys) account on linux (Ubuntu / Freebsd)

Tags: security, zfs, proxmox

Firstable, pls pardon my english as it's not my 1st language.

I m trying to create an self-destructing log-in account on my critical data storage which are using ZFS as primary file system. An account that in the situation I need to giving out under threat. Let's say this is SD-user.

I have researched online that I could creat a script for a specific user so that it will run every time when that designated user tries to log in.

```
~/.bashrc
~/.profile
~/.login
```

My ZFS which is encrypted with a few raw keys file in `/root/keystore/` on a usb drive which acts as a bootable system (`proxmox`/`truenas`).

In the script I planned to :

- use `srm` to securely remove all file in my `/root/keystore/*`
- delegating ZFS permission to this SD-user to destroy all previous snapshot of the USB (so key recovery from snapshot can't done)
- force unmount all current dataset
- then reboot

but the problems is should I create such user as sudoer?  If so how can I run the script without that user typing the password? I wanted the script to run fully automatic, in the background for the obvious reason.

Or is there any way I can run this script as `root` in the background only if this particular user logs in?

Or is there any problem with my idea? Please kindly advise.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107739/how-to-trigger-a-system-self-destruct-with-a-certain-password-is-entered https://www.kali.org/blog/emergency-self-destruction-luks-kali/ https://superuser.com/questions/40814/how-to-set-a-linux-ditribution-to-self-destruct-to-wipe-everything-from-the-sys

Comment: Aaarrr thx for your ref .... but I have read that those solution but I think it’s it’s too much hassle... especially the DD option . And it’s took too much time to execute. If my way do it properly it should took no longer then 1 sec to destroy the keys (and snapshot). Not to mention I have to implement the whole different encryption with all my dataset. 

Also I wanted it work without my attention at all. And I will be able to recover thr data later with reinstalling the destroyed encryption key. ( which ofcoz I will store/backup completely off site )